# Set Paper Options on java crystal reports

Tags: java, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am having a problem whenever I preview a report on my java program. When I open my report and set the paper size to legal then save, the report can be previewed as legal. But when I open it on my java program, it previews on a letter instead of a legal paper. (It looks like my program automatically sets it to "No Printer (optimized for screen display)" on the crystal report designer page setup). I am using Crystal Reports XI.

Comment: By the way, I am using the JRC package (com.crystaldecisions.reports.sdk.ReportClientDocument) instead of (com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportClientDocument)

Comment: this question looks very much the same as your other question about the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206271/set-paper-on-crystal-reports-xi-java